# process.stdin stream is empty inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, stream

In my main app.js file i have a method looking like this

```
function streamToClient(clientName){    
     process.stdin.pause();
     waitForClient(clientName, function(client){
          process.stdin.pipe(net.connect({
              host: client.addresses[0],
              port: client.port
          }));
          process.stdin.resume();
    });
}
```

In it i try to pipe the stream from stdin into a tcp connection a create with net.connect.

The tcp connection is established just fine but the stdin stream is empty and nothing is written...

the waitForClient method just waits until a client with a certain name is available and calls the callback function with a client object containing information about the client.

**So my question is:** WHY is the process.stdin stream empty at that point? what am i doing wrong? if i do

```
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout)
```

inside the callback the stream is empty, but if is do it outsite the callback the stream is not empty....